# Geodesics through two given points

Tags: differential-geometry

For me, from the [definition of a geodesic](http://books.google.de/books?id=wd-sXTUGk98C&pg=PA29):

> Let $\gamma : t \rightarrow \gamma(t)$, $t \in I$, be a curve in a manifold $M$.
>   The curve $\gamma$  is called a geodesic if the family of tangent
>   vectors $\dot\gamma(t)$ is parallel with  respect to $\gamma$.

it is not obvious, that for any two given points in a connected manifold $M$ there is a geodesic passing through them. Is this so?

Comment: I guess $M$ is assumed to be connected.

Comment: You are right, I fixed this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Think about $M=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ with respect to the standard metric. Then all geodesics in $M$ are straight line. Now consider the points $p=(1,0)$ and $q=(-1,0)$ in $M$. There is no straight line joining $p$ and $q$ because $(0,0)$ is not in $M$.

In fact, $M$ is called geodesicaly complete if for any two given points $p$ and $q$ in $M$, there is a geodesic joining $p$ and $q$. And Hopf-Rinow Theorem says that $M$ is geodesicaly complete if and only if $M$ is complete as a metric space. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem). So the above example $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is not complete as a metric space, as we know from calculus.